# How to use version control with an existing website and external hosting?

Tags: git, ftp, bitbucket

I'm looking to apply version control to an existing web project which is currently hosted on 1&1 domains. There are 7 websites under the same hosting package with SSH access.

I've downloaded Source Tree, created a new repository and FTP'ed my files from the host to my local drive. I've also set up a BitBucket account and imported the repository.

My question is - is there a way to automatically commit my changes to BitBucket and at the same to my hosting package? At the moment, I can only see that I make changes locally and then FTP the new files to my server.

Can anybody please tell me whether I'm missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploy web project under GIT version control to shared hosting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970289/deploy-web-project-under-git-version-control-to-shared-hosting)

Comment: You miss FTPloy from "Related" questions

Comment: Thanks - I'll check out the link